# how mail server determine the recipients email address

Tags: email, smtp

I have an email address say: support@mycompany.com.

I registered this email in Google app AND in another mail service provider. Now there are two places that could receive a mail that sends to support@mycompany.com

How does mail server determine which place to send to?

Maybe it depends on the way mail server look up the address?

If I use gmail to send to support@mycompany.com the Google app will receive this email.

If I use webform(like a "Contact us" link in my company's website), the other mail box will receive this email.

Can anybody tell me why? Maybe mail server has their own sequence to look up the recipients in other mail servers? As soon as they find one server accept this recipient's address, it will send out?

Answer (score 1):

In your DNS settings, you have something called the MX records, this tells where your mail should go.

It seems like you have a DNS issue between your domain name and your webhost. Where your Domain Name (at somewhere like namecheap) has a DNS and your Website also has a separate DNS. Your website host' DNS that was not configured to the same MX records on your main domain for your Google Apps.

Just open up both DNS settings and copy the google ones to the other.

Have a look at this http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125

Answer (score 1):

So this has to do with DNS. DNS is a system that allows one to convert a text name like support@mycompany.com to an IP address which allows your mail to be routed to its right destination. For emails the dns system uses a MX Record.

In your specific case when you send an email via GMAIL their servers first do a DNS lookup on their local DNS servers. On those DNS servers the google app has authority and so they route the message there. If you send an email from a non-google site however, whomever has authority per the IANA rules will give you the IP address to mail the message to. In this case its your other mail server.

Here are some more readings:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

It would be best to modify your mx records on google/your other mail server so there is only one authority for that email address.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to modify the mx record on Google App or other mail server. I would imagine I need to modify the mx for sender right? Like my website host, if I modify the mx to insert google mail server, then the website will send email to Google App right?

Comment: So DNS is hierarchical. Glazing over most of the details consider a tree rooted at R with three children A B C. A has a child Google and B has child D. C has child E. Let's say D is your website host for the domain mycompany.com. If someone from E tries to email you it goes to C and says who is mycompany.com. C most likely would say I dunno the first time and say ask R. R would say oh that't located at D go talk with D. Now if someone from google tries to talk with mycompany.com their DNS server at A would get a hit right away. And say oh its local talk with my local server.

Comment: This means there are infinite potential sender MX records you could edit. What you need to do is edit the ones with authority. E.g. the one at google should be pointing to D or vice versa. You want one authoritative record. Whether that's google or your website server that's just an implementation choice.